Problema using a style.css for my website theme
I'm creating my website in on Wordpress.com and I'm implementing my theme.
I created a folder in wp-content/themes/mytheme and in this folder I created an index.php and a style.css.
Basically my style.css doesn't want to apply to my page. Here is my CSS and PHP code
index.php:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <title><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></title>
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>
<body <?php body_class(); ?>
    <div id="content">
        <h1>Hello there!</h1>
        <p>This is my website</p>
    </div>
    <?php wp_footer(); ?>
</body>
</html>

style.css:
body {
  background-image: url('wp-content/themes/miotema/images/prima.jpg') !important;
  min-height: 100vh !important;
  background-color: rgba(234,234,234,0.5);
  background-attachment: scroll !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-size: cover;
  padding-top: 100px;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
}

I tried to put all in my php code adding the line:
style="background-image: url('wp-content/themes/miotema/images/prima.jpg') !important; background-size: cover !important; background-position: center !important;">

and in this case the style that I put in phh applies succesfully.
Is there a problem in linking the CSS to the PHP file? Is this a problem of Wordpress that has priority on my style.css?

where did you ever link to that css file in the head element?

I think I don't, I'm new to PHP, HTML and CSS. I now added a link href in the head in this way:  but it doesn't work

You need to enqueue your stylesheet:
Add this to functions.php. If you don’t have a functions.php you will need to add one.
    function mytheme_enqueue_styles() {
        // Get the current theme's directory and enqueue the stylesheet
        wp_enqueue_style('mytheme-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
    }

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_enqueue_styles');


With that I don't see my style.css applied, I see  only "function mytheme_enqueue_styles() {
// Get the current theme's directory and enqueue the stylesheet
wp_enqueue_style('mytheme-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');
}
" written on the white page

Now it worked, don't now what is changed
